# Contains em Lista de Classe

Tags: c#

Tenho minha classe, que tem 2 classes dentro dela.

```
public class ProfEsp {
public Especilidade Especialidade {get;set;}
public Profissional Profissional {get;set;}

}
public class Especialidade {
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class Profissional {
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Então tenho minha lista

```
var lista = new List<ProfEsp>();
```

Eu quero verificar se existe uma especialidade dentro dessa lista

Tentei usando `var lista.Any(x => x.Especialidade == Esp);`

Com `contains` não tem como também

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: quais são os atributos de Especilidade?

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta Tuyoshi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Relativamente ao .Contains()

O método `.Contains()` da `List<T>` tem uma particularidade que é usar o comparador retornado pelo EqualityComparer.Default. Segundo a documentação:

> A propriedade Default verifica se T implementa a interface System.IEquatable e, em caso afirmativo, retorna um EqualityComparer que usa essa implementação. Caso contrário, ele retorna um EqualityComparer que usa as substituições de Object.Equals e Object.GetHashCode fornecido por T.

Ou seja pode implementar a interface `IEqualityComparer<T>` na sua classe ou então fazer o override do método `base.Equals()` e vai ser esse o método de comparação utilizado.

**Mas porque implementar `IEqualityComparer<T>`?**

Quando usa o `.Equals()` da interface, existe a garantia que os tipos do objecto original e o objecto a comparar são iguais. Não só torna mais segura a programação, como tem um ligeiro impacto na performance, dado que, ao contrário do `base.Equals()` não ocorre boxing/unboxing na comparação.

Este cenário torna-se mais importante quando existe uma extensa utilização de comparações onde os custos da operação de boxing/unboxing deixe de ser negligivel.

#### Any Vs Contain

Uma análise interessante é a comparação de complexidades entre o `.Any()` e o `.Contains()`.

O `.Contains()` é um método da instância e por isso a complexidade está dependente da colecção em si. No caso de uma `List<T>` a complexidade é O(n), enquanto que num `HashSet` a complexidade seria O(1).

Já o `.Any()` é uma extensão cuja complexidade é sempre O(n), dado que vai percorrer toda a colecção, aplicar o delegate passado a cada elemento e retornar quando encontrar um elemento cujo delegate devolva `true`.

Por fim, o `.Any()` devido ao delegate, é mais fléxivel que o `.Contains()` que apenas aceita um objecto.

Answer (score 3):

O `Any` funciona, entretanto você provavelmente você está comparando objetos de especialidade diferentes, mas que parecem ser iguais, por terem os mesmos valores nas propriedades.

Tente comparar uma propriedade que identifique `Especialidade`:

```
var lista.Any(x => x.Especialidade.Id == Esp.Id)
```

Ou então implemente o operador `==` para o tipo `Especialidade`:

```
public static bool operator ==(Especialidade x, Especialidade y) 
{
    return x.Id == y.Id;
}
```

E também o método `Equals`... para manter a consistência com o operador acima.
Ai neste caso poderia fazer da forma que você estava tentando com o `Any`:

```
var hasAny = lista.Any(x => x.Especialidade == Esp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode procurar pelo nome ou Id no exemplo abaixo estou procurando pelo nome

```
var ProfEsp = lista.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Especialidade.Nome == "Programador" );
if(ProfEsp!=null){
  // achou especialidade!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso existe a necessidade de você implementar uma customização deste operador com regras especificas para comparação entre objetos, caso não exista é comparado o HashCode de cada objeto, um exemplo de comparação:

```
public class Especilidade 
{
    public string Nome  { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(Especilidade a, Especilidade b)
    {
        // mesma instancia, retorna true.
        if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Caso um deles sejam nulos, retorna false
        if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Retorna true se o campos forem iguais
        return a.Nome == b.Nome && a.Categoria == b.Categoria;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Especilidade a, Especilidade b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

Veja esta documentação, vai te ajudar com comparações entre objetos:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Eu testei e funcionou assim:

```
var listaProfEsp = new List<ProfEsp>();

     var lista1 = new ProfEsp();
     lista1.Especialidade = new Especialidade
     {
         Id = 1,
         Nome = "teste"
     };

    listaProfEsp.Add(lista1);            
    var exist = listaProfEsp.Any(x => x.Especialidade.Id == lista1.Especialidade.Id);

    if (exist)
    {
       Console.Write("exist");
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
       Console.Write("não exist");
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Funciona mas não existe procura pelo item. A unica coisa que está a fazer é confirmar que existe pelo menos uma especialidade não nula dentro de `listaProfEsp`.

Comment: Mas pelo que entendi ele quer ver se existe um entidade dentro por isso que ele queria usar o contains, se for para verificar se uma em especifico existi dai ele procuraria por Id, nome ... etc

Comment: Correcto, ele queria ver se existe uma especialidade especifica dentro da lista, não se existe uma qualquer. Concordo que a pergunta possa parecer que ele quer ver apenas se existe algo lá dentro, mas dado que o OP diz `var lista.Any(x => x.Especialidade == Esp);`, foi assumido que ele queria procura algo em especifico.

Comment: Acabei de ler novamente e você esta certo alterei lá...

Comment: A unica coisa que acrescentaria é para, em vez de usar `idEspecialidade`, acesse directamente a propriedade `ID` de `lista1`.

Comment: Concordo alterei lá ficou até mais fácil para exemplificar...