# Cláusula in com lambda

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

É possível ter uma cláusula IN com lambda expression?
Tipo:

```
context.tabela.Where(a => a.meu_campo_id_tipo_inteiro....)
```

digamos um in assim:
(2,3,4,5)
Como coloco nos pontinhos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mais ou menos. O jeito de fazer é assim:

```
var inteirosPraAchar = new List<int> {2, 3, 4, 5};
context.tabela.Where(a => inteirosPraAchar.Contains(a.meu_campo_id_tipo_inteiro));
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa ao método na resposta do [@Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18912/8113):

```
List<int> inteirosParaAchar = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
context.Where(i => inteirosParaAchar.Any(i1 => i1 == i));
```

Pelas razões apontadas nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16745/8113) (relativamente à flexibilidade), o uso do Any torna a comparação mais flexível e pode ser estendida para incluir mais elementos de comparação.

Excerto da resposta:

> Por fim, o .Any() devido ao delegate, é mais fléxivel que o .Contains() que apenas aceita um objecto.

Comment: Boa alternativa. +1.

Comment: Desculpa, o incomodo, mas, eu não utilizaria esse método, porque, vocês (@CiganoMorrisonMendez e Ommi) sabe qual SQL ele vai gerar?

Comment: @HarryPotter Nunca testei. Qual?

Comment: Com a sua resposta ele gera um `in(1,2,3,4)` com `Any` ele usa Exits e escreve uma Sql Unioll All para para cada item no  `WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM  (SELECT          [UnionAll8].[C1] AS [C1] FROM  (SELECT              [UnionAll7].[C1] AS [C1] FROM  (SELECT                   [UnionAll6].[C1] AS [C1]` se tiver 100 itens ele gera um big SQL desnecessária ao meu ver!. Exite a fusão de SQL In com Exits mas, a codificação é diferente desta! E olha sou bem preocupado com o que a codificação gera!

Comment: VEESH! Zoado, hein? Bom, mas se for pra poucos acho que não tem problema.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, só é uma dica depois eu venho apagando tal informação, não quero criar mau estar !!! obrigado!

Comment: Nah, deixa aí. Vai ser útil pra alguém.

Comment: @HarryPotter facto interessante. Alguma alternativa? Eu por regra geral tento evitar INs, mas uma alternativa era interessante de se saber.

Comment: @Omni, eu utilizo assim, `in` quando for um dado fixo, e `exits` quando eu precisar varrer uma outra SQL, mas, nos dois casos a `SQL` é uma linha, e nesse caso proposto por `Any` é gerado uma grande SQL e acredito que ai a performática do `Entity` fique ruim. Eu perguntei uma vez a um DBA SQL Server e Oracle eles dizem que hoje tanto o `in` quanto o `exits` tem performática parecida, mas, o problema que que nessa `Any` ele gerou uma grande SQL olha no link: http://codepad.org/jREAd5EM, tipo foi um array de 1 até 10.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez dá uma olhada no resultado: http://codepad.org/jREAd5EM