# Como utilizar a cláusula IN em Lambda?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Surgiu uma duvida que pensei que seria fácil, porem o conteúdo que encontrei não consegui entender.

Bom é o seguinte:
Tenho as tabelas

> "Cliente"

e

> "ErrosProducao_Cliente"

onde elas se relacionam de forma 1 para N, ou seja, 1 erro pode afetar N Clientes.

Sendo assim preciso fazer em lambda exatamente a consulta SQL abaixo:

```
select * from Cliente 
where Id_Cliente in (select CodCliente 
                     from ErrosProducao_Cliente 
                     where codErro = 1)
```

Sei que posso resolver esse problema com um `Join`, porem gostaria de descobrir como é feito o usando IN.

Diferente da pergunta citada abaixo nas resposta o meu problema queria realizar o `IN` diretamente através de um `subSelect`.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18909/cl%C3%A1usula-in-com-lambda

Comment: Faça um select dos códigos dos clientes dentro de um array, e olhe o ouro link. Porém a performance com join é melhor pelo que já li.

Comment: Consegue me dar um exemplo de como ficaria o join nesse caso?
Retornando uma lista da tabela Cliente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça algo assim.

```
using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
{

    var qrInSubCategoria = ctx.Cliente
        .Where(C => ctx.ErrosProducao_Cliente.Any(EC => EC.CodCliente== C.CodCliente && C.codErro == 1));
}
```

Ou

```
using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
{
    var listint = ctx.ErrosProducao_Cliente
        .Where(EC => EC.codErro == 1)
        .Select(EC => EC.CodCliente)
        .ToList();

    var qrInSubCategoria = ctx.Cliente
        .Where(C => listint.Contains(C.CodCliente));

}
```

Ou ainda usando .Distinct() no seu código cliente.

```
using (var ctx = new stackoverflowEntities())
{
    var listint = ctx.ErrosProducao_Cliente
        .Where(EC => EC.codErro == 1)
        .Select(EC => EC.CodCliente)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

    var qrInSubCategoria = ctx.Cliente
        .Where(C => listint.Contains(C.CodCliente));

}
```

Comment: Brigadão parceiro!!!

Comment: Ficou muito boa a solução poderia ter usado um `Distinct()`, para não repetir código do Cliente

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4, desculpa mas, você está enganado.

Answer (score 2):

```
// pegar os códigos do clientes e jogar na lista
var codigos = context.ErrosProducao_Cliente.Where(e => e.codErro == 1).Select(e => e.CodCliente).ToList();
// aqui seleciona os clientes que contenham na lista gerada acima
var clientes = context.Clientes.Any(c => codigos.Contains(c.codCliente)).ToList();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado parceiro!!!

Comment: De nada. Você só pode marcar uma resposta como aceita, ok? Você tinha marcado a minha e depois marcou outra, sem problemas, marque a que atendeu melhor.

Comment: Ficou muito boa a solução poderia ter usado um `Distinct()`, para não repetir código do Cliente

Comment: Sim, mas no SQL passado não havia. Fiz ao pé da letra o que foi pedido hehe

Comment: Boa dica pros próximos leitores Virgilio, no meu caso eu não permito o cadastro dessas tabelas incluir dois clientes pra um mesmo erro.

Comment: Sim, claro @Murilo, eu inclusive votei a favor, só coloquei mais um cereja no bolo, visto que isso seria uma otimização no código do usuário.